TYPO3 Fluid: Error "UnknownNamespaceException ... Unknown Namespace"
I'm getting this error:

TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Parser\UnknownNamespaceException
Fluid parse error in template Show_action_list_82f0dce1f900c37e76f4b68e54e043a07b887b2f, line 20 at character 1. Error: Unknown Namespace: xyz (error code 0).

with this annotation:
{xyz:myviewhelper()}

and this error:

#1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception
PHP Warning: Array to string conversion in \vendor\typo3fluid\fluid\src\Core\Parser\SyntaxTree\AbstractNode.php line 73

with this annotation:
<xyz:myviewhelper/>

I've imported ViewHelper namespace:
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
      xmlns:xyz="https://typo3.org/ns/Xyz/Xyz/ViewHelpers"
      data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">

Everything is working as expected with this import:
{namespace xyz=Xyz\Xyz\ViewHelpers}

Environment is TYPO3 v12, PHP 8.2, Windows 10

Problem was url protocol - I had to use xmlns:xyz="http://typo3.org/ns/Xyz/Xyz/ViewHelpers" instead of https.
No idea, why. In earlier TYPO3 versions (v10), this was no problem.

It's because that's what Fluid expects for the automatic NS registration:
https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/blob/d37b945aaf8b556a5eb5bb0fe4cb7958956a82ed/src/Schema/ViewHelperMetadataFactory.php#L101 Notice that this is not an URL but a namespace, a unique identifier.
